# I need help combining this two graphs into one in R

Tags: r, regression

Can anyone help me combine these two charts showing Gender 0 and Male 1

```
## When Gender = 0

int<- -3.4839
FC<- -0.5278
FCV<-seq(1,4,by=.5)
EY<-plogis(int+FC*FCV)

plot(EY~FCV,type="o",col.lab="black", cex.lab=1,col.axis="black",col="purple",xlab="Family Cohesion When Gender is ", ylab="Expected Probability of Binge Drinking", mar=c(7,7))


## When Gender = 1


int<- -3.4839+ -0.6433 
FC<- -0.5278
FCV<-seq(1,4,by=.5)
EY<-plogis(int+FC*FCV)

plot(EY~FCV,type="o",col.lab="black", cex.lab=1,col.axis="black",col="blue",xlab="Family Cohesion", ylab="Expected Probability of Binge Drinking", mar=c(7,7))
```

Comment: See `?points` and `?lines`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

```
int<- -3.4839
FC<- -0.5278
FCV<-seq(1,4,by=.5)
EY<-plogis(int+FC*FCV)

plot(EY~FCV,type="o",col.lab="black", cex.lab=1,col.axis="black",col="purple",
xlab="Family Cohesion When Gender is ", ylab="Expected Probability of Binge Drinking", 
mar=c(7,7),ylim=c(0,0.02))

int<- -3.4839+ -0.6433 
FC<- -0.5278
FCV<-seq(1,4,by=.5)
EY<-plogis(int+FC*FCV)

lines(EY~FCV,type="o",col.lab="black", cex.lab=1,col.axis="black", col="blue",
xlab="Family Cohesion", ylab="Expected Probability of Binge Drinking", mar=c(7,7))
```

I simply added an xlim=c(0,0.02) to the first `plot` call and replace `plot` by `lines` in your second call.